# Set value in another spreadsheet Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a button as a trigger for my script. When the script triggers it needs to paste "1" into another spreadsheet. What's the script/code for this? :D I got the button figured out.. Plz help! :D

Answer (score 0):

You could use setValue(), setValues(), copyTo() and perhaps others as well. I learned it from [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference), read it for yourself.